# rEFIt menu takes around 10 seconds to even show up

Tags: unix, efi

I'm using a macbook pro 8,1. I've installed rEFIt so that I can dual boot with Ubuntu. This is all "working" except that each time I turn on my laptop, it takes ten or fifteen seconds to even get to the rEFIt menu for me to select an OS.

At this point, I have done nothing special except to make Ubuntu the default OS and reduce the wait time in the rEFIt menu from 20 to 5 seconds.

How can I reduce this lag between startup and OS selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have rEFIt installed on one of the partitions on the hard drive, the following steps should remove the delay:

- Boot via the Mac OS X Install DVD/USB.
- Launch Terminal (Utilities Menu).
- Enter `diskutil list` to list all available disks and partitions.
- Looking at the list of partitions for "disk0" (internal drive), identify the partition that contains your rEFIt boot files.
- Enter `bless --setBoot --device /dev/disk0s2 --legacy` assuming that "/dev/disk0s2" was the rEFIt partition.
- Enter `reboot` to reboot your Mac

Your Mac should now boot to rEFIt with a minimal delay.

The same method also works with Windows 7 direct booting (Boot Camp) which can present an extremely long boot delay on MacBook Airs and Minis if Windows 7 is your startup disk and the above steps have not been taken.